# Live streaming is not continous in my application using NexPlayer

Tags: android

Live streaming is not continuous in my application using NexPlayer. It takes around 10 secs of buffering. What I want is to have a large buffer initially but once streaming starts then buffering should happen in the background, and streaming will be going on meanwhile. Is this possible using async task? Has anyone worked on NexPlayer stream video? Please let me know, as it is very critical for my application.

Comment: please supply relevant source code so we would be able to help you

Comment: In order to help you please tell us what protocol you are using, RTMP, Smoothstreaming, HLS etc. When properly configured (the streaming server and the nextreaming client) you should not see any buffering during playback in normal conditions. So please give us more information so we can help you find the cause of  your problem.